# Reversing a vararg

Tags: lua, variadic-functions

Given a vararg `...` like `1, 2, 3, nil, 5`, I would like to write a function `reverse`, such that `reverse(...)` returns the vararg `5, nil, 3, 2, 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a temporary table:

```lua
local function reverse(...)
    local n = select("#", ...)
    local t = {...}
    -- Reverse the table
    for i = 1, n/2 do
        local j = n - i + 1
        t[i], t[j] = t[j], t[i]
    end
    return unpack(t, 1, n)
end
```

or using a helper function which picks the `n`-th element, prepends that to a new vararg, and recurses until `n = 0`:

```lua
local function h(n, ...)
    if n == 0 then return end
    return select(n, ...), h(n - 1, ...)
end
local function reverse(...)
    return h(select("#", ...), ...)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in dropping down a level, the Lua C API provides [`lua_insert`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_insert) and [`lua_rotate`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_rotate) (5.3+), both of which can be used to manipulate the stack directly.

An example using the former:

```
#include <lua.h>

static int reverse(lua_State *L)
{
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        lua_insert(L, i);
    return n;
}

int luaopen_reverse(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_pushcfunction(L, reverse);
    return 1;
}
```

```lua
local reverse = require 'reverse'

print(reverse(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

```
4   3   2   1
```

---

(*The following focuses on the Lua 5.4 API, but should be applicable to Lua 5.3 as well. Note that in Lua 5.3+, `lua_insert` is a macro around `lua_rotate`.*)

Interestingly, there is an internal API function called [`reverse`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lapi.c.html#reverse), used by `lua_rotate`, which performs this task very efficiently across a stack segment.

If one has the ability to change the source code for their installation, then it is possible to modify [*src/lapi.c*](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lapi.c.html) with the following function,

```
/* reverse the entire stack segment */
LUA_API void lua_reverse (lua_State *L)
{
    lua_lock(L);
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    if (n > 1)
        reverse(L, index2stack(L, 1), index2stack(L, n));
    lua_unlock(L);
}
```

[*src/lua.h*](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.h.html) with the following protoype,

```
LUA_API void  (lua_reverse) (lua_State *L);
```

[*src/lbaselib.c*](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lbaselib.c.html) with the following function,

```
static int luaB_reverse (lua_State *L) {
    lua_reverse(L);
    return lua_gettop(L);
}
```

and add

```
{"reverse", luaB_reverse},
```

to the [`base_funcs`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lbaselib.c.html#base_funcs) array in [*src/lbaselib.c*](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lbaselib.c.html), to get access to an efficient, global `reverse` function:

```
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> reverse('hello', 'world', 42)
42  world   hello
```

(*and a `lua_reverse` C API function, of course.*)